# Hibernate cannot open Connection

Tags: hibernate, tomcat

I am trying to read record for the database using hibernate and my code is working fine on console application. But when i try the same code for servlet it gives the following error i am using Tomcat.
I already include odbc6.jar file in Eclipse.I am using Oracle11g.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Cannot open connection


type Exception report

message Cannot open connection

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3294)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
com.hibernate.dao.BookDAOImpl.read(BookDAOImpl.java:27)
com.servlet.SelectServlet.doGet(SelectServlet.java:36)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


Root cause
ava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3294)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
com.hiberate.dao.BookDAOImpl.read(BookDAOImpl.java:27)
com.servlet.SelectServlet.doGet(SelectServlet.java:36)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
```

and my configure file look like this

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<property name="connection.driver_name">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
<property name="connection.username">system</property>
<property name="connection.password">tiger</property>

<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<mapping resource="com/hibernate/config/book.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Your code would be helpful to track down the problem.

Comment: please make sure if the Database driver Jar file is in the classpath

Comment: try oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver and make sure the driver is in the classpath

Comment: i already put jar files.

Comment: Where did you put them?

Comment: lib folder of WEB-INF